# jQuery FAQ Accordion only open one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page on a site that has multiple FAQ questions where when you click the " + " the answer slideToggle's. I'm having an issue where on click all of the answers for all questions open, and I want to be able to toggle one at a time.

Is there a way I can do this using "parent" "child" selectors in jQuery?

HTML:

```
                <div class="main-slide">
                    <div class="main-slide-title">
                        <p>One-time Close Purchase/Construction Loans</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-slide-plus">
                        <p>+</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-slide default-hidden">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Finance the construction</li>
                        <li>Purchase of lot</li>
                        <li>Permanent loan</li>
                        <li>FHA, and VA are available</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".main-slide-plus").click(function () {
  $(".sub-slide").slideToggle(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes from the HTML piece you provided, you can get the parent `main-slide` and then toggle the sibling with class `sub-slide`

So something like

```
$(".main-slide-plus").click(function () {
  $(this).parents(".main-slide").sibilings(".sub-slide").slideToggle(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is the structure you have repeating for the accordion, you will need to go to the parent, then find the next .subslide element. Along the lines of the following:

```
$(".main-slide-plus").click(function () { 
   $(this).parent().next(".sub-slide").slideToggle(500); 
});
```